# Why am i not getting a new view for the recyclerview

Tags: android

I am doing a shopping cart. I am sending the data from ItemClickedFragment to ShoppingCart using shared preferences. Also i am using an adapter to create a new view for new data that is sent. My problem is view works fine but i do not get a new view for the new data, instead just the fields get replaced with the incoming data. Codes are below please help, i've been stuck for 3 days.

ItemClickedFragment.java (Where i send the data to ShoppingCart.java)

```
 public void shoppingCart(){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences2 = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS2,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences2.edit();
        editor.putString("name",name);
        editor.putString("course",course);
        editor.putString("page",page);
        editor.putString("price",price);
        editor.putString("uni",uni);
        editor.putString("imageUrl",imageUrl);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

ShoppingCart.java (The main fragment)

```
public class ShoppingCart extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private List<CartModel> cartModelList;
    private CartAdapter adapter ;

    public static final String SHARED_PREFS2 = "sharedprefs2";
    TextView cartName;
    TextView cartCourse;
    TextView cartUni;
    TextView cartPage;
    TextView cartPrice;
    String image;
    String name;
    String course;
    String uni;
    String page;
    String price;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shopping_cart, container, false);
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        recyclerView = requireView().findViewById(R.id.ShoppingRecycler);
        cartName = requireView().findViewById(R.id.cartName);
        cartCourse = requireView().findViewById(R.id.cartCourse);
        cartUni = requireView().findViewById(R.id.cartUni);
        cartPage = requireView().findViewById(R.id.cartPage);
        cartPrice = requireView().findViewById(R.id.cartPrice);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(requireActivity().getApplicationContext()));

        //Get the shared preferences
        getItems();

        cartModelList = new ArrayList<>();
        CartModel cartModel = new CartModel(image,name,uni,course,page,price);
        cartModelList.add(cartModel);

        adapter = new CartAdapter(cartModelList, requireActivity().getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
    public void getItems(){
        //Get the shared preferences
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS2,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        name = sharedPreferences.getString("name","");
        course = sharedPreferences.getString("course","");
        uni = sharedPreferences.getString("uni","");
        page = sharedPreferences.getString("page","");
        price = sharedPreferences.getString("price","");
        image = sharedPreferences.getString("image","");
    }
}
```

CartModel.java

```
package com.example.uninotes;

public class CartModel {
    private String image;
    private String name;
    private String uni;
    private String course;
    private String page;
    private String price;

    public CartModel(String image, String name, String uni, String course, String page, String price) {
        this.image = image;
        this.name = name;
        this.uni = uni;
        this.course = course;
        this.page = page;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getUni() {
        return uni;
    }

    public String getCourse() {
        return course;
    }

    public String getPage() {
        return page;
    }

    public String getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

CartAdapter.java

```
public class CartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<CartModel> cartModelList;
    private Context context;

    public CartAdapter(List<CartModel> cartModelList, Context context) {
        this.cartModelList = cartModelList;
        this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).
                inflate(R.layout.shopping_cart_items,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         CartModel cartModel = cartModelList.get(position);

         //Set the data to positions
         holder.name.setText(cartModel.getName());
         holder.uni.setText(cartModel.getUni());
         holder.course.setText(cartModel.getCourse());
         holder.page.setText(cartModel.getPage());
         holder.price.setText(cartModel.getPrice());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cartModelList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        ImageView image;
        TextView name;
        TextView uni;
        TextView course;
        TextView page;
        TextView price;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            //Get the shopping_cart_items views
            image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartImage);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartName);
            uni = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartUni);
            course = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartCourse);
            page = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartPage);
            price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cartPrice);
        }
    }
}
```

shopping_cart_items.xml (This is the cartview that is being replaced instead of creating a new one)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <!-- Your CardView layout -->
    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="115dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cartImage"
                android:layout_width="130dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/books2">
            </ImageView>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cartName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000">
                </TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cartUni"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp"
                    android:textColor="#000000">
                </TextView>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/cartCourse"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp">
                </TextView>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp">
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cartPage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="#000000">
                    </TextView>
                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/cartPrice"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
                        android:gravity="end"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:textSize="16sp"
                        android:textColor="#000000">
                    </TextView>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I was expecting to get new views for the new shared preferences that is sent, but the program replaces just the TextViews instead.

Comment: Hi @Korhan_34, *This is the cartview that is being replaced instead of creating a new one*. This is because you have only one item in your `cartModelList`. The recyclerview will create more views as you add more items to the `cartModelList`. Just don't forget to call adapter's `notifyItemInserted` method everytime you add a new item into the `cartModelList`.

Comment: But variables change as the new insertion. Shouldn't it be generating a new view for the changing variables

Comment: No matter how many times those variables change. There is no new insertion here. You always create only one `CartModel` object, therefore there will be always only one `CartModel` in the `cartModelList` whenever the `ShoppingCart` fragment gets created. How many `CartModel` in the list, there will be that many views on the screen. For testing purposes, create another `CartModel` other than the one you send through shared preferences, and add it to the list before creating the adapter. Then you should see 2 views in the screen.

Comment: How can i implement the logic of creating a new view as the new variables come

Comment: //CartModel instances
        CartModel cartModel2 = new CartModel(image,"kfmvk","cvfv","cdcd","cfdcd","ce");
        CartModel cartModel = new CartModel(image,name,uni,course,page,price);

        //Add them to cartModelList
        cartModelList.add(cartModel);
        cartModelList.add(cartModel2); I added two cartModels like this but i still get single view